# Do different things in the same function depending on which html component called that function

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am making a basic toggle app in angular.I have two toggle buttons.I am displaying a message in toggle.I want to call the same function on toggle change but do different things depending on which button was toggled.Is it possible or do I have to use two different functions? Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is my template code:

```
<mat-card class="card" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" >
<form class="example-form" [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()" ngNativeValidate>

  <mat-action-list>
    <mat-list-item > <mat-slide-toggle       
      (change)="onChange($event);displayMessage($event)"   formControlName="Policy1" >
      <span class="label">{{message}}</span></mat-slide-toggle></mat-list-item> 
    <mat-list-item > <mat-slide-toggle  (change)="onChange($event)"  formControlName="Policy2">Policy2</mat-slide-toggle></mat-list-item>

  </mat-action-list>
  <p>Form Group Status: {{ formGroup.status}}</p>

  <button mat-raised-button [disabled]="disable" class="button" type="submit">Save Settings</button>

</form>
</mat-card>
```

The funtion that I'm calling from the toggle button:

```
  displayMessage(e){
    if(e.checked)
    {
      this.message = 'Toggled';
    }
      else
      this.message = 'Slide';

  }
```

Comment: Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-heiutf

Comment: could you please provide a stackblitz example?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I am trying to do it in one function only instead of having different function

Answer (score 2):

The `$event` object from the `(change)` emitter has a `srcElement` that you can refer to when you want to find out which element caused the change.

If you want to retrieve the id of the element that called the function you do so with `event.srcElement.id`

Comment: This will probably work but is not quite Angular-y. @mbojko answer is more idiomatic

Comment: I am unable to retrieve the id.I am getting error  Cannot read property 'id' of undefined when I try to fetch the id using e.srcElement.id.Any change I have to do in the template code?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass more arguments to the handler:

```
<mat-slide-toggle *ngFor="let item of thingsToDo; let i = index"
   (change)= "onToggle($event, item.id, i)">
```

```
onToggle = (event, id, indexInArray) => { //...
```